# Is it possible to override an implicit object contained within a trait that is being extended?

Tags: scala, spray-json

I have a wrapper trait that extends BasicFormats from spray json https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/release/1.3.x/src/main/scala/spray/json/BasicFormats.scala

but I would like to override the behavior of `implicit object BigDecimalJsonFormat extends JsonFormat[BigDecimal]` to add rounding logic. Example being

```
import spray.json._
import scala.math.BigDecimal.RoundingMode

case class Foo(i: BigDecimal)
object Foo extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val roundedBigDecimalProtocol: JsonFormat[BigDecimal] =
    new JsonFormat[BigDecimal] {

      def write(f: BigDecimal) = JsNumber(f.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))

      def read(json: JsValue): BigDecimal =
        DefaultJsonProtocol.BigDecimalJsonFormat.read(json)
    }
  implicit val fooFormatter = jsonFormat1(this.apply)
}
```

scastie snippet: 
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/9RNhajzGRDGMX5QsuAohVA

Answer (score 0):

Great question, I wasn't even aware this may cause so many problems. The solution I am about to propose is probably not the cleanest, but it does the job... First of all, you don't have to extend `DefaultJsonProtocol`, you might also import it's members:

```
object Foo {
  import DefaultJsonProtocol._

  implicit val roundedBigDecimalProtocol: JsonFormat[BigDecimal] = ...
  implicit val fooFormatter = jsonFormat1(this.apply)
}
```

This doesn't solve the problem but that way you can *exclude* some of the members so that they are not imported. Here's the syntax for that

```
import DefaultJsonProtocol.{BigDecimalJsonFormat => _, _}
```

It basically says: don't import `BigDecimalJsonFormat` but import the rest.

And the following code sums it up.

```
import spray.json._
import scala.math.BigDecimal.RoundingMode

case class Foo(i: BigDecimal)
object Foo {
  import DefaultJsonProtocol.{BigDecimalJsonFormat => _, _}

  implicit val roundedBigDecimalProtocol: JsonFormat[BigDecimal] =
    new JsonFormat[BigDecimal] {

      def write(f: BigDecimal) = JsNumber(f.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))

      def read(json: JsValue): BigDecimal =
        DefaultJsonProtocol.BigDecimalJsonFormat.read(json)
    }
  implicit val fooFormatter = jsonFormat1(this.apply)
}
```

Comment: Running this locally, roundedBigDecimalProtocol throws a warning that it's not used. 
I also updated the scastie example to show that by printing out an object
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/9RNhajzGRDGMX5QsuAohVA